# Nested array of objects filtering - es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So below is the array of objects and I'm trying to filter only the objects which have `type:y`. As you see the array of objects can also contain nested array of same schema and it can be N-level nested. So please help me with most optimized ES6 function to achieve this.

```
[
    {
        name: 'a',
        type: 'x',
        array:
            [
                {   
                    name: 'l',
                    type: 'y',
                },
                {   
                    name: 'm',
                    type: 'y',
                },
                {   
                    name: 'n',
                    type: 'x',
                    array:
                        [
                            {   
                                name: 'x',
                                type: 'y',
                            },
                            {   
                                name: 'y',
                                type: 'y',
                            },
                            {   
                                name: 'z',
                                type: 'x',
                            }
                        ]
                }
            ]
    },
    {
        name: 'b',
        type: 'y',
    },
    {
        name: 'c',
        type: 'y',
    },

]
```

Also below is the code which I have written to achieve this. *looking to improve the performance and optimize it*

```
filterFunction(fields) { 
    const result = [];
    (fields || []).forEach((field) => { 
      if (field.array) {
        const x = field;
        x.array = this.filterFunction(field.array);
        result.push(x);
      } else if (field.type !== 'x') {
        result.push(field);
      }
    });
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: If you have working code that you're simply looking to improve, your question could be considered off-topic for StackOverflow, but instead suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What is `arrayDefinition`? Also, your sample code seems to also include objects, which have a sub-array, but are of type "x". Why you create `const x` is also a mystery to me.

Comment: @ASDFGerte sorry, I updated my code - it was supposed to be array. I want to include the object if it contains any object which has `type:x`.  Also I'm creating `const x` as I cant manipulate the field directly.

Comment: Note that `const x = field`, where `field` is an object, does **not** create a copy of the object - it simply uses the same reference. So i still don't fully understand the purpose of `const x`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a fold like pattern:

```
function walkRec(input, accumulator, state = []) {
  if (!(input instanceof Array)) input = [input];
  for (const item of input) {
    state = accumulator(item, state);
    const isObject = item !== null && typeof item == 'object';
    if (isObject && 'array' in item)
      state = walk(item.array, accumulator, state);
  }
  return state;
}
```

if the tree you have to filter is big (lot of subtree) you may get a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" Error and you will probably prefer this kind of iteration:

```
function walk(input, accumulator, state = []) {
  if (!(input instanceof Array)) input = [input];
  while (input.length > 0) {
    const item = input.shift();
    state = accumulator(item, state);
    const isObject = item !== null && typeof item == 'object';
    if (isObject && 'array' in item) {
      const children = item.array instanceof Array ? item.array : [item.array];
      Array.prototype.push.apply(input, children);
    }
  }
  return state;
}
```

and use it as following

```
walk(array, (item, state) => {
  if (item && item.type == 'y')
    state.push(item)
  return state;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the array by using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for new objects with deeper filtered arrays.

```js
function filter(array, type) {
    return array.reduce((r, o) => {
        var array = filter(o.array || [], type);
        if (o.type === type || array.length) {
            r.push(Object.assign({}, o, { array }));
        }
        return r;
    }, []);
}

var array = [{ name: 'a', type: 'x', array: [{ name: 'l', type: 'y', }, { name: 'm', type: 'y', }, { name: 'n', type: 'x', array: [{ name: 'x', type: 'y', }, { name: 'y', type: 'y', }, { name: 'z', type: 'x', }] }] }, { name: 'b', type: 'y', }, { name: 'c', type: 'y' }];

console.log(filter(array, 'y'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer but if I do `filter(array, 'y')` it removes the first object as its `type:x` but ignores the fact that it has nested object which has `type:y`. Also it creates empty array on every object

Comment: do you want to keep nested objects with the wanted type?